# Wrong Shell for user and $SHELL value

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-shell

The default shell of my user somehow changed to /bin/sh even though it's set in /etc/passwd to /bin/bash.

I can't seem to be able to change it to any other value, I mean I can change it but the set value is not taken into account.

Changing it with *chsh* makes no difference.

```
$ echo $BASH $SHELL
/bin/sh
$ grep user /etc/passwd
user:x:1000:1000:User,,,:/home/user:/bin/bash
$ chsh
Password: 
Changing the login shell for user
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Login Shell [/bin/bash]: /bin/bash
$ echo $BASH $SHELL
/bin/sh
$ su root
Password: 
root@elitebook1:/home/user# echo $BASH $SHELL
/usr/bin/bash /bin/bash
root@elitebook1:/home/user#
```

Comment: You need to logout and login again to see changes. Can you please confirm if the issue persists after re-logging in?

Comment: I just rebooted and now the correct shell is used. Thanks

Comment: The reboot essentially logged you out :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently logging out was necessary for the change to be taken into account. Issue solved!

Comment: Just logging out... nothing more or less!